# Cos'è un "tubo pescante"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Zolfo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Prelevò un campione dalla caldaia, lo lasciò raffreddare e lo saggiò col reattivo: la provetta rimase limpida qualche secondo, e poi diventò bianca come il latte. Lanza spense il fuoco, fermò l’agitazione e la ventola, ed aperse il rompivuoto: si sentí un lungo fischio rabbioso, che piano piano si andò placando in un fruscio, in un mormorio, e poi tacque. Avvitò il **tubo pescante**, mise in moto il compressore, e gloriosamente, in mezzo a fumi bianchi ed all’aspro odore consueto, il getto denso della resina andò a placarsi nella bacinella di raccolta in un nero specchio lucente.

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è un "tubo pescante"?

Ho cercato alla voce "tubo" di parecchi dizionari, ma non appare questa espressione. Quello che ho trovato per "pescante" sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pescante/) e sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00164.jpg) non sembra avere senso nel contesto del testo. Una ricerca su Google di "tubo pescante", però, dà parecchie occorrenze.

Comment: Sembra un tubo che tramite il compressore aspira un liquido da un recipiente per poi depositarlo in un altro. Giusto per esemplificazione https://www.manomano.it/p/sabbiatrice-walmec-asturo-pneumatica-con-tubo-pescante-pistola-per-sabbiatura-6450953

Comment: In questo spaccato si vede il tubo che "pesca" il liquido https://shop.polatoferramenta.com/167258-thickbox_default/access-gdm-pompa-pressione-tubo-pescante.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prendendo dalla [definizione di pescare dal vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pescare/) (qui il participio presente è usato come aggettivo):

> 3. Di nave e di qualunque imbarcazione, avere lo scafo immerso nell’acqua per una maggiore o minore altezza (v. pescaggio): *la nave pesca cinque metri*. **Anche, per estens., di altri oggetti che sono parzialmente immersi in un liquido**: *il timone pesca fino a metà (o pesca poco, troppo); portando ogni tanto alle labbra la cannuccia che pescava nella bibita* (Bassani).

Dunque un tubo "pescante" è immerso almeno in parte in un liquido (o gas) e, come fa notare @Hachi, la sua funzione è di solito quella di aspirare il liquido stesso per esempio tramite un compressore.

Si può parlare anche di *tubo di aspirazione*

Alcuni spaccati che illustrano il concetto:

[image: Spaccato 1]

[image: Spaccato 2]

Anche questi spruzzini usano un tubo pescante:

[image: Spruzzini]
<sub>(source: [eticastore.it](https://www.eticastore.it/3126-home_default/spruzzino-nebulizzatore-piramidale-da-330-ml.jpg))</sub>